# scanf is causing my code to run on forever

Tags: c, scanf

I was trying to use `scanf` but when I run the code the code goes on forever. And when I stop the code I get

> [Done] exited with code=1 in 28.291 second

My question is what am I doing wrong? Here is the code I was trying to execute. My editor is VS code 1.21.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char midInitial;

    printf("What is your middle initial? ");

    scanf(" %c", &midInitial);

    printf("Middle inital &c ", midInitial);
}
```

Comment: Apart from the wrong format specifier in the second `printf` and the missing `\n` in both of them I don't see anything wrong and I am unable to reproduce the issue: https://ideone.com/QfiOms Also you should mention which compiler you use rather than which editor

Answer (score 1):

The code does not *run forever*, it is waiting for the user to complete the input. Standard input is line buffered, so the user must type enter after the character for `scanf()` to process it. It will skip any white space characters, store the first non white space character into `midInitial` and return `1`.

Another possible explanation is the environment you use does not support console input. Run your program from shell interpreter window in Windows.

There is another problem: the format `"Middle inital &c "` is incorrect, use `%` for conversion specifiers.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char midInitial;

    printf("What is your middle initial? ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &midInitial) == 1) {
        printf("Middle initial: %c\n", midInitial);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
    char midInitial;

    printf("What is your middle initial?\n");

    scanf(" %c", &midInitial);

    printf("Middle initial %c ", midInitial);
}

Comment: @ chqrlie: I figured what I was doing wrong. I was trying to type in the output terminal instead of the terminal where one can actually type commands in such as ls. Anyways thank you so much for helping out. As you can tell I am a newbie if not worst.

Answer (score 1):

go to code-runner extention setting and make sure <Code-runner: Run In Terminal>
checked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

int main(){ char midInitial;

printf("What is your middle initial? ");

scanf(" %c", &midInitial);

printf("Middle inital %c ", midInitial);   (see it should be %c)
}

Comment: A typo in the format specifier would not cause an endless loop. Also please format your code properly and make sure it actually compiles

Comment: I’m using MinGW / gcc. Also I used the ideone Texteditor and it worked fine. So probably something wrong with the compiler.

Comment: *Also please format your code properly*... Your answer does not give any hint as to how to do that, and it does not compile either ;-)